# Get customer email in form input field on OpenCart 2.0 page

Tags: php, forms, input, field, opencart2.x

Hi I have a form that has various inputs.  This form is on one of my category pages.  I'm trying to prefill one of the inputs with the users email when logged in.  Anyone know a way I can achieve this with OpenCart.  I'm really new to this and any help or direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

INPUT:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a library function `getEmail()` on

```
system\library\customer.php
```

Which returns the logged in customer Email

```
$data['email'] = $this->customer->getEmail();
```